# How did nested group in regex work in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex which has nested group in it, the returned result does match my expectation, can anyone tell me why?

```py
input_string = "(;A[B][D];B[C])"
regex_str = r'\(;([A-Z]+(\[\w+\])+)*(.*)\)'
result = re.findall(regex_str, input_string)
```

I expected the output to be:

```
[('A[B][D]', '[B][D]', ';B[C]')]
```

However, the actual output is:

```
[('A[B][D]', '[D]', ';B[C]')]
```

Why didn't `(\[\w+\])+` match '[B][D]' instead of '[D]'?

Comment: There is no nested anything in your string.

Comment: `( \[ \w+ \] )+` did match `[B][D]` just one at a time. The last thing a group matches is retained with the group. In this case `[D]` is the last thing group 2 matched.

Comment: @sln Thanks!!! I knew what my problem is!